# Not running the same service multiple times in different apps

Tags: android, service

I have a Service to gather some data and have Application A already installed on my device. I am about to release Application B with the same service.

If the user has A previously installed I don't want the Service in Application B to run. On the other hand, if the application B is the first installed on the device, I want that Service to run, and if A in installed after, Service from application A shouldn't run.

```
Service S
Application A : Service SA
Application B : Service SB

If A is installed on the device before B -> SB should never run, only SA
If B is installed on the device before A -> SA should never run, only SB
```

To note that A and B are not signed with the same keystore.

Comment: and what is your problem actually?

Comment: Not sure how to approach the problem. Content providers? before running one of the services. I need to check that any of the other apps doesn't have that service, and that it ran at least once (the app was open at least once). Maybe an open shared preference? Not a fan of the openness but well...

Comment: `PackageManager#queryIntentServices (Intent intent, int flags)` "Retrieve all services that can match the given intent."

Comment: That's a good way to find out if another app has a Service but I'm not sure it means the user opened the app at least once, thus the service ran at least once or not

Comment: no, `ResolveInfo` does not store such info